# 'backwards' enumerate

Tags: python

Is there a way to get a generator/iterator that yields the reverse of `enumerate`:

```
from itertools import izip, count

enumerate(I) # -> (indx, v)
izip(I, count()) # -> (v, indx)
```

without pulling in `itertools`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
((v, indx) for indx, v in enumerate(I))
```

if you really want to avoid `itertools`. Why would you?

Comment: because it seemed like overkill and I was curious

Comment: @tcaswell Importing something and using code that already exists is never really overkill. That said, in this case, it's probably not the most readable way to do it.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not sure about this particular case but in general `itertools` is faster than generator expressions. You should give it a try and compare.

Comment: @ExP Of course, it is worth noting that speed is going to be completely irrelevant 99% of the time for something like this - don't bother optimizing unless it's a proven bottleneck. Readability is far more important.

Comment: @Lattyware Importing extra modules (that would not otherwise be imported) to do something that can be done more readable without any imports might not be overkill, but it is inelegant.  Feel kinda dumb I didn't see this solution.

Comment: @tcaswell In this situation, yes, but in general, you shouldn't be afraid of importing `itertools` - it's a module that is almost universally useful.

Comment: @Lattyware I love `itertools` and use it heavily ;)

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with a simple [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(some_iterable))
```

Here as a list comprehension to easily see the output:

```
>>> [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(["A", "B", "C"])]
[('A', 0), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question right. But here is my solution.
Based on the code on: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

```
def enumerate_rev(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield elem,n
        n += 1
```